# WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart() for JSR223 Sampler

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jsr233

I am using JSR223 Sampler and I want to start calculating time after url load so my code as below :

**

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","/Users/geckodriver");
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions().setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);
options.addArguments("--headless");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
def wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
driver.get('https://google.com/');
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//input[@name='q']")));
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd();
```

**

Comment: I basically need to start calculating time after driver.get() .i used function sampleStart();/sampleEnd(); ended up with below error :                                              
   2020-10-07 16:08:11,096 ERROR o.a.j.p.j.s.JSR223Sampler: Problem in JSR223 script JSR223 Sampler, message: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.sampleStart() is applicable for argument types: () values: []

Answer (score 1):

[JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) automatically calculates its duration depending on your script contents so if you want to measure the time required to find an input you have to options:

1. Create another JSR223 Sampler which will open the required page and store the WebDriver instance into [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) like:

   - First JSR223 Sampler:

     ```
     import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
     import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
     import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions;
     import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
     System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","/Users/geckodriver");
     FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions().setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);
     options.addArguments("--headless");
     WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
     def wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
     driver.get('https://google.com/');

     vars.putObject('driver', driver)
     vars.putObject('wait', wait)
     ```
   - Second JSR223 Sampler:

     ```
      import org.openqa.selenium.By;
      import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;

      def driver = vars.getObject('driver')
      def wait = vars.getObject('wait')
      wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//input[@name='q']")));
     ```
2. Use [SampleResult.addSubResult()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#addSubResult-org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult-boolean-) function to create a "child" sample result which will measure the time required to locate the element:

   ```
   import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
   import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
   import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions;
   import org.openqa.selenium.By;
   import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
   import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
   System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","/Users/geckodriver");
   FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions().setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);
   options.addArguments("--headless");
   WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
   def wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
   driver.get('https://google.com/');

   def myResult = new org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult()
   myResult.setSampleLabel('Locating element')
   myResult.sampleStart()
   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//input[@name='q']")));
   myResult.setResponseCodeOK()
   myResult.setSuccessful(true)
   myResult.sampleEnd()

   SampleResult.addSubResult(myResult,false)
   ```

   in this case you will get something like:

   [image]

Check out [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) to learn more about these `vars` and `SampleResult` shorthands

Comment: thanks, @Dmitri,I believe option 2 will suit me more with my current requirement but its throwing same error again.

Comment: 2020-10-07 18:58:21,636 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started
2020-10-07 18:58:21,636 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: FirefoxeBrowser 1-1
2020-10-07 18:58:25,427 ERROR o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleEnd called twice
java.lang.Throwable: Invalid call sequence
 at org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult.sampleEnd(SampleResult.java:1145) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
 at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JSR223Sampler.sample(JSR223Sampler.java:82)

Comment: I copied the above script a ran it.

Comment: I switched to Optioned 2 , thanks for the help, it resolves my issue.